# Prove or disprove convergence of a series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Assume  $\sum_{n=k}^{\infty} a_n$ converges.
Then $\sum_{n=k}^{\infty} a_n \cdot a_{n+2}$ converges?

I think I should disprove it, because $\sum_{n=k}^{\infty} a_{n+2}$ might diverge but I can't find a disproof.

Comment: Clearly if $\sum_{n=k}^\infty a_n = L$ converges, then $\sum_{n=k}^\infty a_{n+2} = L - a_k - a_{k+1}$, hence it will also converge.

Comment: @Zubzub And this helps because?

Comment: @Did I'm not saying this help, just that the argument proposed by OP doesn't work. Indeed the hint of Robert Z is what we should consider.

Comment: @Zubzub I understand.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Hint. Consider the sequence $a_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}$ for $n\geq 1$.

Comment: And note that such an example is basically necessary, since there are no counterexamples where $\sum a_n$ converges absolutely.